# SQL Server login fails from C# Web app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I created a user on the SQL Server but using that login I get this message:

```
Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.]
```

Here is my connect string:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Server=SRV-02;Initial Catalog=OCIS_logins;Integrated Security=True;user id=TEST;password=test" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

I am sorry for this possible bad question but I normally do not have anything to do with SQL server admin...

I hope you can help me please.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Integrated Security=True to Integrated Security=False

Comment: Getting closer. Now I get a different message:

Cannot open database "OCIS_logins" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'OCIS'.

Thank you for your fast help.

Answer (score 2):

Bookmark this site http://www.connectionstrings.com  it has all kind of examples

here it is for sql server 2005 http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

so in your case it should be

```
connectionString="Server=SRV-02;Initial Catalog=OCIS_logins;user id=TEST;password=test" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I will bookmark it. The sample here did not work for me.